# Magento Instead of displaying my Block Popular Tags block shows up from default theme

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have been working on the magento Blocks in my custom module. Everything is working fine Controller is okay and the rest of things working good. The problem I am facing is that my block is not shown up as expected. Instead of showing my block or block message, 'popular tags' block shows up. Here is my module Experiment/Test/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <experiment_test>
            <vresion>0.0.1</vresion>
        </experiment_test>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <experiment>
                    <class>Experiment_Test_Block</class>
                </experiment>
            </blocks>
        </global>
        <routers>
            <experiment>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Experiment_Test</module>
                    <frontName>experiment</frontName>
                </args>
            </experiment>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <experiment>
                        <file>experiment.xml</file>
                    </experiment>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

My config file for module is app/etc/modules/Experiment_Test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Experiment_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Experiment_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here is my Experiment/Test/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
<?php
class Experiment_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
?>
```

Here is my block places: Experiment/Test/Block/ExpBlock.php:

```
<?php
class Experiment_Test_Block_Expblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function methodblock(){
        return 'Information About my Block!!';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my layout file placed in design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/experiment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">

    <default>
        <reference name="content"></reference>
    </default>

    <experiment_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="test/expblock" name="afficher_expbloc" template="experiment/afficher.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </experiment_index_index>

</layout>
```

And here is my template file that is placed in design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/experiment/afficher.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->methodblock(); ?>
```

But the output shown up from another block, that is from popular_tags block and **frontend/base/default/template/tag/popular.phtml**

Please let me know where I made mistake.

Comment: try to insert your experminet.xml in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout to see if it helps

Comment: then flush the cache

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong block definition inside your layout file

```
<block type="test/expblock" name="afficher_expbloc" template="experiment/afficher.phtml" />
```

This is wrong. Instead of this, you need to use this

```
 <block type="experiment/expblock" name="afficher_expbloc" template="experiment/afficher.phtml" />
```

`experiment` is the block unique identifier name that you have set through your `config.xml` file. There for in order to point to your `Experiment_Test_Block_Expblock`, you need to use the type `experiment/expblock` for your custom block in layout file.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but still it is not displaying as expected.

Comment: did you get the message from your block and output in frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issue in your code:

first config.xml

`experiment_test` should be  `Experiment_Test`

**from**

```
   <modules>
        <experiment_test>
            <vresion>0.0.1</vresion>
        </experiment_test>
    </modules>
```

**to**

```
 <modules>
        <Experiment_Test>
            <vresion>0.0.1</vresion>
        </Experiment_Test>
    </modules>
```

File name `ExpBlock.php` should be `Expblock.php`

and change:

```
 <block type="test/expblock" name="afficher_expbloc" template="experiment/afficher.phtml" />
```

to

`<block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>`

Comment: No that was fine, it worked using this.. so that was not the issue though there were issues in the config.xml - I found out, and shared here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well I found solution myself after figuring out in deep and that is I had declared some of the tags wrong in my config.xml file (Experiment/Test/etc/config.xml) - So I think to share so it would be helpful for someone who having the same situation: Here is my corrected config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <experiment_test>
            <vresion>0.0.1</vresion>
        </experiment_test>
    </modules>

    <frontend>

        <routers>
            <experiment>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Experiment_Test</module>
                    <frontName>experiment</frontName>
                </args>
            </experiment>

        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <experiment>
                    <file>experiment.xml</file>
                </experiment>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <experiment>
                <class>Experiment_Test_Block</class>
            </experiment>
        </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

I also had problem in my layout file that is answered by @programmer_rkt